# Управление Google Street View кнопкой (Button)

Tags: android

Как по нажатию кнопки (у меня метод public void oCl(View view)) управлять локацией и/или камерой? Никак не получается изменить поворот или перемещение (для начала не важно что), улица отображается но по нажатии на кнопку - программа вылетает. (мне нужна ИМЕННО кнопка). Буду рад любой подсказке! (про гугл в курсе, уже налазился)

```
package com.zarubaandrej.facebook.arutor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {
    StreetViewPanorama streetView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewFragment =
                (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        streetViewFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(MainActivity.this);}


    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
        streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(47.517487, -122.20154330000000));
    }

    public void oCl(View view) {
        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .tilt(-30)
                .bearing(-30)
                .build();
        streetView.animateTo(camera, -10);
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.user.googlestreetview13, PID: 14497
                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama.animateTo(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera, long)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.zarubaandrej.facebook.arubainkarnator.MainActivity.oCl(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Смотри логи - там ошибка. Прикрепи логи к вопросу

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanorama.animateTo(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera, long)' on a null object reference

В логе сказано что **streetView** на момент вызова **streetView.animateTo(camera, -10);** в функции  **public void oCl(View view)** равен null - то есть **не инициализирован**

И действительно объявление переменой есть есть     **StreetViewPanorama streetView;** а инициализации нет!(типа streetView = new StreetViewPanorama(...) )

Я нашел вот такой код(за работоспособность не отвечаю)

```
  @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
        streetView = streetViewPanorama;

    }
```